# Association entity related - change by hand

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I do have an entity in AppBundle/Entity which I generated me from database.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

/*
 *
 * ExtensionSyliusShopUser
 */
 class ExtensionSyliusShopUser
 {/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\SyliusShopUser $user
 *
 * @return ExtensionSyliusShopUser
 */
public function setUser(\AppBundle\Entity\SyliusShopUser $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\SyliusShopUser
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

Now I want to change the `setUser() & getUser()` to:

```
Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser
```

If I am going to change @parm and the value in braces e.g.:

```
public function setUser(\Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser $user = null)
```

I get the error:

Expected value of type "AppBundle\Entity\SyliusShopUser" for association field "AppBundle\Entity\ExtensionSyliusShopUser#$user", got "Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser" instead.

How can I change it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
 <entity name="AppBundle\Entity\ExtensionSyliusShopUser" table="extension_sylius_shop_user">
    <indexes>
      <index name="user_id" columns="user_id"/>
    </indexes>
    <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
      <generator strategy="IDENTITY"/>
    </id>
    <field name="wishlist" type="text" column="wishlist" length="65535" nullable="true">
      <options>
        <option name="fixed"/>
      </options>
     </field>
    <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="SyliusShopUser" fetch="LAZY">
      <join-columns>
        <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id"/>
      </join-columns>
    </many-to-one>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the definition of your $user property (column). which is not shown in a code sample you provided.

In case you use annotations is should look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser")
 */
private $user;
```

In case of XML config:

```
<many-to-one field="user" target-entity="Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShopUser">
```

Comment: Where do you have your mapping definition?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint! It is working. I forgot to set the target-entity="SyliusShopUser" to target-entity="Syliusy\...\SyliusShopUser".